# Overload function with parameters constrained or find a way to do elsewhere

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a function named NotNull that will work like ".?".

For example :

```
a.NotNull( x => x.AFunc )
```

If a is null, NotNull return a generic type of AFunc otherwise NotNull return the return value of AFunc.

I have written :

```
public static TReturn NotNullClass<TObject, TReturn>(this TObject obj, Func<TObject, TReturn> func) where TReturn : class
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return func(obj);
    }
}

public static TReturn NotNullStruct<TObject, TReturn>(this TObject obj, Func<TObject, TReturn> func) where TReturn : struct
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return new TReturn();
    }
    else
    {
        return func(obj);
    }
}
```

The issue is that didn't succeed to regroup both function in one generic function by doing an overload or doing a static test if TReturn is a class or a struct.

How can I write this with only one generic function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static TReturn NotNull<TObject, TReturn>(this TObject obj, Func<TObject, TReturn> func)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
        {
            return default(TReturn);
        }

        return func(obj);
    }
```

This extension method can be used for both reference types and values types (for TObject). For value types (structs) the condition is always true and will call the given func.

Due to `default(TReturn)` this method works for both reference and value types for TReturn too.

Comment: In this case "default" do a perfect job, ty. But I wonder if there is a way to resolve this kind of overload ...

Comment: default of a class equals null

Comment: You don't need two different versions.